# How can I read records from an avro file in the order it’s written using Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, avro

I have an avro file containing a number of records. I want to maintain the order of the data as it’s been written in the file. I have no property to sort on that can give me this.

How can I read data from an avro file and guarantee the order is as it is stored in the file? Is there anyway to get a sequential row number or equivalent which represents its position within the file?

Comment: what approach you tried? any error you are facing?

Comment: I’m not aware of any approach. I can’t find any detail on how the data is read and what guarantees I’d have on ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Avro files are typically not indexed by row position, and their design is optimized for schema evolution and columnar storage, not row-level access.

To assign a sequential row number using `monotonically_increasing_id()` is a common workaround to assign a unique identifier to each row within a DataFrame.

The `monotonically_increasing_id()` function generates unique, increasing values for each row in a DataFrame but does not consider the original order of the data in the file.
It generates unique IDs based on the partition and task ID of the DataFrame, which may not reflect the original order.

The below code adds a new column named "**row_number**" to the DataFrame df. The values in this column are generated sequentially for each row using the `monotonically_increasing_id()` function. This function assigns a unique, increasing ID to each row in the DataFrame.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ReadAvroWithOrder").getOrCreate()
avro_file_path = "abfss://folder02@dileepstoragegen2.dfs.core.windows.net/sample.avro"
df = spark.read.format("avro").load(avro_file_path)
df = df.withColumn("row_number", monotonically_increasing_id())
df.show()
```

[image]

If you want to maintain the original order of the data as it was written to the Avro file, you can use the orderBy function to sort the DataFrame by the sequential row number that you assigned.
This will essentially restore the original order of the data:

```
df = df.orderBy("ID")
df.show()
```

[image]